# How to add missing numbers to a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have an array list. Which contains month number and data as comma separated.
Now I want to loop through this list and check if any month number is missing. If then need to add that month number in order with data part as zero.

```
  List<string> MyData = new List<string>();
  MyData.Add("4,500"); //dynamically adding. 4(april) and 6(june) are month numbers.
  MyData.Add("6,400");
  foreach (string str in MyData)
        {
  int GetmonthNum = Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(',')));
        }
```

Now need to add all other missing month number with value as zero. The resulted List should be

```
"4,500","5,0","6,400","7,0","8,0","9,0","10,0","11,0","12,0","1,0","2,0","3,0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `contains` like this

```
        var result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12 ; i++)
        {
            var firstMatch = myData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(i + ","));

            if (firstMatch == null)
            {
                result.Add(i + ",0");
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(firstMatch);
            }
            // or short code: result.Add(firstMatch ?? i + ",0" );
        }
```

If you want "4,500" is the first item then try it

```
        var minMonth = myData.Min(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf(",", StringComparison.CurrentCulture))));

        var result = new List<string>();
        for (int i = minMonth - 1; i < minMonth + 11; i++)
        {
            var firstMatch = myData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith((i % 12) + 1 + ","));
            result.Add(firstMatch ?? (i % 12) + 1 + ",0");
        }
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the resulted output in "4,500","5,0","6,400","7,0","8,0","9,0","10,0","11,0","12,0","1,0","2,0","3,0"  format ?

Comment: Do you want to convert List to string or to set  "4,500" is the first item?

Comment: Want to set first item as itself. and then repeat other months in order. EX: if the first item is april. then new array list should be from april,may,june,...march

Comment: @user2431727 When minMonth is assigned as 2(feb) it is not working properly. getting feb,march,april,may,apr,july,may,sep,oct,nov,dec,jan

Comment: What is your problem? minMonth = 2 then feb is the first item. Or What do you want?

Comment: if myData contains month numbers in order 2,3,4,5. When trying with your code, I got 2,3,4,5,4,7,5,9,10,11,12,1. that is 4th and 5 th month is repeating when find mode of 12

Comment: I just tried my second code with 2,3,4,5 input. It returns 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1 without duplicate. Did you change anything?

Comment: Only change that I made is mydata contains 5 data now. Ex  MyData ="2,100,200,300,400","3,100,200,300,400","4,100,200,300,400","5,100,200,300,400"

Comment: That doesn't change my result. I have just retried it.

Comment: please try with  List<string> myData = new List<string>();
        myData.Add("2,100,200,300,400"); 
        myData.Add("3,100,200,300,400");
        myData.Add("4,3236,200,300,400");
        myData.Add("5,100,800,300,400"); you can find the issue

Comment: I know the issue.

Comment: Just change Contains to StartsWith. I just edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case if there are 12 item in your list [respective to 12 month] try below code

```
List<string> MyData = new List<string>();
            MyData.Add("4,500"); //dynamically adding. 4(april) and 6(june) are month numbers.
            MyData.Add("6,400");
            int i = 1;
            // use variable i from 1 to 12 as month indicator
            foreach (string str in MyData)
            {
                string month = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(',')); 
                // get the month from your list item here
                int GetmonthNum = Convert.ToInt32( month==string.Empty || month==null ? i.ToString() : month  );
               // here use conditional operator to check if month is not there in list item , if it is not present than return i as misisng month 
                i++;
            }
```

Let me know if you feel any problem in putting the code together

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve your desired result with the following loop. There are many ways to do it though.

```
int arrayIndex = 0;
int month = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    if (myArray[arrayIndex].Split(',')[0] == Convert.ToString(month))
    {
        MyData.Add(myArray[arrayIndex]);
        month++;
        arrayIndex++;
    }
    else
    {
        MyData.Add(Convert.ToString(month) + ",0");
        month++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> MyData = new List<string>();
        MyData.Add("4,500"); 
        MyData.Add("6,400");

        var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12);
        foreach (int month in months)
        {
            if (MyData.Any(a =>  a.Split(',')[0] == month.ToString()))
            continue;
            MyData.Add(string.Format("{0},{1}", month.ToString(), "0"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
MyData =
    MyData
        .Select(x => x.Split(',').Select(y => int.Parse(y)).ToArray())
        .Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new [] { x, 0 }).ToArray())
        .OrderBy(x => x[0])
        .GroupBy(x => x[0], x => x[1])
        .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1), (y, z) => $"{y.Key},{z}")
        .ToList();
```

And that gives:

```
1,0 
2,0 
3,0 
4,500 
5,0 
6,400 
7,0 
8,0 
9,0 
10,0 
11,0 
12,0
```